# Incorrect date labelling in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having a weird issue with date labeling in X-coordinates. It labels fine on my local machine but on remote AWS it is not labeling correctly. No issue of data. Only labeling having issues.
[image]

As you can see I labeled both correct and incorrect labeling. The versions mentioned here are matplotlib versions in local and a remote AWS machine. The issue is having a remote AWS machine with the new version(*though I am not sure whether it is a version issue*). The reason one is wrong because despite of the date is 29Jun and new week it still shows label till 22 June

The code is given below for both df preparation and graph generation:

```
import datetime as dt

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import sys
import talib


def generate_signal_df():
    is_qc = False
    dt_string = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1623279604")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    signal = ''
    responses = []

    if is_qc:
        urls = ["https://",
                "https://"]
    else:
        urls = ['http://',
                'http://']

    try:
        if is_qc:
            responses.append(requests.get(urls[0], headers=headers).json()['result']['data'])
            responses.append(requests.get(urls[1], headers=headers).json()['result']['data'])
        else:
            responses.append(requests.get(urls[0], headers=headers).json())
            responses.append(requests.get(urls[1], headers=headers).json())

        df1 = pd.json_normalize(responses[0])
        df2 = pd.json_normalize(responses[1])
        df_open_yoi = df2

        if not is_qc:
            df1.set_index('ts', inplace=True)
            df2.set_index('ts', inplace=True)

            df1['close'] = pd.to_numeric(df1["close"])
            df2['xz'] = pd.to_numeric(df2["xz"])

        dfo = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

        # df_stock = dfo.drop(['price_usd_open', 'price_usd_high', 'price_usd_low'], 1)
        df_stock = dfo

        df_stock.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)

        # Perform Calculations

        price_ema_a = talib.EMA(df_stock['close'], timeperiod=12) - talib.EMA(df_stock['close'],
                                                                              timeperiod=26)
        price_ema_c = price_ema_a - talib.EMA(price_ema_a, timeperiod=9)
        df_stock['price_ema'] = price_ema_c

        ema_a = talib.EMA(df_stock['xz'], timeperiod=12) - talib.EMA(df_stock['xz'],
                                                                                  timeperiod=26)
        ema_c = ema_a - talib.EMA(ema_a, timeperiod=9)
        df_stock['yoi_ema'] = ema_c

        df_stock['signal'] = np.where(df_stock['yoi_ema'] > 0,
                                      np.where(df_stock['price_ema'] > -10, 'BUY', 'SELL'), "NOACTION")

        final = df_stock.copy().dropna(subset=["yoi_ema"])

        final["usd_total"] = 0.0
        final["btc_total"] = 0.0
        final["btc_value_usd"] = 0.0
        final["total"] = 0.0

        final["action"] = "None"

        last_row = None
        last_signal = None
        usd_total = 0.0
        btc_total = 1.0

        for index, row in final.iterrows():
            if row["signal"] == last_signal:

                final.loc[index, "action"] = row["signal"] + "-LOCKED" if row["signal"] != "NOACTION" else row["signal"]
            else:
                final.loc[index, "action"] = row["signal"] if row["signal"] != "NOACTION" else str(
                    last_signal) + "-LOCKED"

                last_signal = row["signal"] if row["signal"] != "NOACTION" else last_signal

                if row["signal"] == "BUY":
                    if is_qc:
                        btc_total += usd_total / row["price_usd_close"]
                    else:
                        btc_total += usd_total / row["close"]

                    usd_total -= usd_total
                elif row["signal"] == "SELL":
                    if is_qc:
                        usd_total += (btc_total * row["price_usd_close"])
                    else:
                        usd_total += (btc_total * row["close"])
                    btc_total -= btc_total

            final.loc[index, "btc_total"] = btc_total
            final.loc[index, "usd_total"] = usd_total

            ts_text = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(final.loc[index, "last_ts"])).strftime(
                '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

            final.loc[index, "ts_text"] = pd.to_datetime(ts_text, format='%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

            if is_qc:
                final.loc[index, "btc_value_in_usd"] = final.loc[index, "btc_total"] * final.loc[
                    index, "price_usd_close"]
            else:
                final.loc[index, "btc_value_in_usd"] = final.loc[index, "btc_total"] * final.loc[index, "close"]

            final.loc[index, "total"] = final.loc[index, "btc_value_in_usd"] + final.loc[index, "usd_total"]

        final.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
        final = final.head(50)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return final


def generate_graph():
    is_generated = True
    path = ''

    try:
        if sys.platform != 'darwin':
            path = 'Bot/'

        df = generate_signal_df()
        df['ts_text'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ts_text).dt.tz_localize('UTC')
        df.sort_values('ts_text')

        # Set up the axes and figure
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.bar(df['ts_text'], df['yoi_ema'])

        # Skip every after every third ticks
        # import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
        # myLocator = mticker.IndexLocator(base=3, offset=0)
        # ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(myLocator)

        ax.xaxis.label.set_color('black')
        # ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')

        myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%b')
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
        fig.autofmt_xdate()
        ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
        ax.set_ylabel(“Momentum, color="yellow")
        plt.xticks(rotation=60, ha='left')
        plt.savefig("{}signal_graph.png".format(path), transparent=True, dpi=70)
        # plt.show()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print('Exception in generate_graph routine')
        is_generated = False
    finally:
        return is_generated
```

Comment: Two things I'd try:
(a) Have you got exactly the same version of libraries installed on both?
(b) Matplotlib uses different backends to render the plots. You may be using a different one locally to the one available on AWS (which probably uses offscreen rendering). Try setting explicitly the same backend by adding matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = 'Agg' on both systems.

Comment: @RyanPepper refer to that _backend_ thing, I am generating the image of graph. Isn't that backend thing for the GUI only?

Comment: @RyanPepper Nah, I tried, it did not make any difference.

Comment: The various backends do various things - some render to screen, others render to a file. The defaults can be different on different systems because it depends what was available when matplotlib was installed, and because they depend on system libraries. If it makes no difference though, the next thing I'd check is dumping out the data frame and checking that it's exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: @RyanPepper yes the data is absolutely same because it generates once in a day and I am using same endpoint. There is no issue in ticks. Only issue is in labeling of X-axis of the date.